# prevent access via .htaccess *TO* a given hostname

Tags: htaccess

I have a website which is accessible via several hostnames.

I would like to put something in an .htaccess file that would simply block any request requesting a particular hostname.

For example, say `example1.com` and `hello.somehost.com` both point to the same website. I would like to put something in the .htaccess file that will allow users to view the website if they visit `example1.com`, but will not allow users to view it if they visit `hello.somehost.com`.

You'd think this would be easy to Google but if there are any results out there, they're drowned out by people who want to block access if the user is *coming from* a particular hostname...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently newer versions of apache (2.4) support conditional statements in .htaccess files, although i havent found a reference... just lots of results on other stack exchange sites.

You might also be able to accomplish what you want to do using rewrite rules.

Otherwise, the most obvious place to do this is in your virtual host config.

If you have a global php include file, you could do it there as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using `mod_rewrite`.  Have `mod_rewrite` check for the `HTTP_HOST` and [show a 403 Forbidden error](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hello\.somehost\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```